# Stripping function calls from lines using regex

Tags: regex, vim

Let's say I have a line,

```
$bagel = parser(1);
$potato = parser(3+(other var));
$avocado = parser(3-(var1+var2+var3));
$untouchedtoast = donotremove(4);
```

I want to print, instead of parser(1), just 1.  So I want to strip function calls (matching parser(.) I guess?), but leave the innards untouched.  The output would, ideally, be

```
$bagel = 1;
$potato = 3+(other var);
$avocado = 3-(var1+var2+var3);
$untouchedtoast = donotremove(4);
```

I tried %s/parser(.)//g, but it only replaced everything to the left of the innards.  Tried a few other wildcards, but I think I have to somehow pass a variable from the input regex to the output regex, and I'm not sure if that's possible.  If it matters, I'm doing this in vim.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%s/parser(\(.\+\));/\1;/
```

Search `parser();`, extract everything inside `()` using `\(.\+\)` group, replace the entire expression with the group (`\1`), add a semicolon (because it was eaten by the search expression).

Comment: Works perfectly and explained perfectly.  Completely forgot about regex groups (the actual way to pass a variable from input to output).  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
search: \w\(|\)(?=;)
replace: blank
```